# Switch versions quickly flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to switch `v1.12.13+hotfix.6` and `v1.9.1+hotfix.6` sometimes,
but every time I switch environment by`$flutter version v1.12.13+hotfix.6`

New download start and takes a few minutes.

Same things happen. Is there a way to keep both version in Local and prevent downloading??

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

this is how it is designed, you can request a feature on https://github.com/flutter/flutter